# Prove that the rational numbers are countable - An alternative way

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

There are many answers for this topic in the stackexchange forum but I would like to validate an alternative way of finding that the rational numbers are countable.

The set of rational numbers is defined as $Q = \lbrace \frac{p}{q}: p,q \in Z \rbrace$. So, each number can be writter as $p = aq + r \implies aq = p -r \implies p \equiv r (mod q)$. So, there is the set of residuals $Z_q$. There is also a set $P$ that contains the numbers corresponds to the classes of the $Z_q$. The countable sum of the $Z_q$ is the set $nZ$. We only need to prove that countable union of countable sets is a countable set.

Comment: Are you taking union of $\{0\}, \{0,1\}, \{0,1,2\}, \{0,1,2,3\}\ldots$ (i.e. sets of residuals)? Obviously, there are repeated elements, so, intuitively, the union is *smaller* than the sum of sizes of all sets contributing to it. (Finite case: $\{0\}$ has $1$ element and $\{0,1\}$ has $2$ elements, but $\{0\}\cup\{0,1\}$ has $2$ elements - not $3$.) Thus, if your goal is to cap the sum of the sizes, you are supposed to bound it from *above* but you are bounding it from *below*, so to speak.

Comment: Very Nice !! I have an another question here ! If we have a sum of $n$ sets of integers $Z$ then is the set $nZ$ countable ? If the set is countable then I could change what I wrote "the union of $Z_q$" and I could write the sum of $Z_q$.

Comment: When you say "sum", I presume you mean "disjoint union". Yes, but then your argument is that "disjoint union of countably many countable sets is a countable set", which is pretty much what the whole thing about $\mathbb Q$ being countable *is* about. In other words, you would be "back to square one". Plus, you can make those sets much simpler: $\{\text{fractions with denominator }1\}, \{\text{fractions with denominator }2\}, \{\text{fractions with denominator }3\},\ldots$.

Comment: One could try to argue that showing the disjoint union of countably many finite sets is countable is simpler than showing the disjoint union of countably many countable sets is countable. But it seems to me that the real point is that your assignment of $p/q$ to $p$ (mod $q$) is not one-to-one (as pointed out in the answer below). In fact, this mapping will have infinite fibers. So you actually are left with showing that the union of countably many countable sets is countable. This is the usual proof, and can be done more easily, as Stinking Bishop says.

Comment: @halrankard2 Indeed. Either we have some way to do counting rationals in finite groups (which is possible, but seems to be unsuccessful here), or we are counting them in (countably) infinite groups (which is ok, but this is the crux of what we want to show in the first place). BTW: The usual divide of rationals into finite groups (based on the sum of the numerator and denominator in the reduced form) is also quite simple: $\{0\}, \{1, -1\}, \{2,\frac12,-\frac12,-2\}, \{3,\frac13,-\frac13,-3\}, \{4,\frac32,\frac23,\frac14,-\frac14,-\frac23,-\frac32,-4\},\ldots$

Comment: @StinkingBishop Good point.

Comment: By the way: the set of rational numbers is _not_ defined as $\Bbb Q = \lbrace \frac{p}{q}: p,q \in Z \rbrace$. By this definition, $1/2$ and $7/14$ would be different rational numbers. It is (usually) defined as the set of _equivalence classes_ of $\lbrace \frac{p}{q}: p,q \in Z \rbrace$, where $p/q\equiv r/s$ if $ps=rq$.

Comment: Questions here are meant to present a "static" picture, not a dynamic one.  It would likely be better if you removed the struck-through text, and edited your question so that it clearly presents your thinking without elisions and deleted text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is $7 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$ but $\dfrac{7}{5}\not= \dfrac{2}{5}$ so for  $5$ there are more that $|\mathbb{Z}_5|$ rationals with denominator $5$ so I don't think you count all of the rationals.

After discussion: the exact definition of $P$ is that it is $\mathbb{Z}$ and every time there is $P\to \mathbb{Z}_q$ for a different $q\in\mathbb{Z}$. So in order to show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable it remains to be shown that countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Yes this is true ! But... Don't we claim that if the set of residuals is countable then all classes of this set are countable too ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't get your point

Comment: What I want to say is that: If we have a set of numbers $P$ that can produce a countable set (set of residuals), then can the set $P$  be considered as countable ?

Comment: But what does "produce" mean? Do you mean union? Like if $\cup P$ is countable then $P$ is countable?

Comment: Let assume that there is a set of residuals $Z_q$. This set is countable and contains the classes $\bar{0},...,\bar{{q-1}}$. We assume that there is a set $P$ where each number corresponds to a class. For example, $\bar{0} = \bar{q}$. My question is: Can we consider that the set $P$ is also countable ?

Comment: No. Suppose $P=\mathbb{R}$ and to each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ I correspond $\overline{[x]}$ (where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$)

Comment: I think that $P \subset Z$ because based on the definition of the set $Q$ above the $p$ and $q$ are integers and also the residual $r$ is integer. Thus, the $P$ can not be the set of $R$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113639/discussion-between---and-dimitris-dimitriadis).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, your particular encoding may not work, but there are other ways to encode rationals as integers.

One example is to map $(p,q)$ to "$\text{length}(p)\, 0\, p\, q$".
Where $\text{length(x)}$ is simply a unary encoding of $p$ -- that is a string of 1's as long as $p$.

Then you might write

- $7/3$ as $1\, 0\, 7\, 3$.
- Or $100/17$ as $111\, 0\, 100\, 17$.

Since you can always recover the original fraction, the encoding is a bijection, and since it maps into the integers you have shown that the cardinality of the fractions is the same as that of the integers.